# Elements not centered after JQuery .click Event (despite transform-origin adjustment)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, center

As seen in the JSfiddle below, after the click event occurs two span (block) elements rotate 45deg to form an "X". However, both elements are pulled slightly left to form an "X" that is slightly off-center of the parent's true center-origin.

I would greatly appreciate a demonstration on how to have my "X" form in the parent's true center. Also, if someone can find an answer elsewhere it is greatly appreciated as my searches have come up empty.

Currently I am using the following "transform-origin" to form the "X"after the click event:

```
transform-origin: 21% 50%;
```

Without it, things are really a mess.

Here is the JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/STEEZENS/L74p1ok3/

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="hamburger-icon" title="Menu">
<span class="line line-1"></span>
<span class="line line-2"></span>
<span class="line line-3"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired result by changing the `transform-origin` to an absolute value (px) and adding `translateX`, in addition to the rotation, to compensate(?) for the apparent translation that existed, previously.

https://jsfiddle.net/voz8Lnhd/1/

```
#hamburger-icon .line {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    transform-origin: 21px center;
}
#hamburger-icon.active-rotate .line-1 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(6px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(6px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(6px);

}
#hamburger-icon.active-rotate .line-3 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(6px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(6px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(6px);
}
```